# how to output tags that has specific value in slug

Tags: tags, slug

How can i output tags thats has value "-en" in slug
I have slug which looks like this "term1-en","term1-de" and so on. And how can i correctly only those tags that has "en" in their slug.

This what i tried so far.

```
$tag = post_tags(); 
foreach($tag as $tags) {
 if(strpos($tags->slug, '-en') !== false) { 
 echo $tags->name;
}};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should re-consider your tag structure, if you must search for sub-strings, to be able to use it. Otherwise you can try e.g.

```
$terms = get_terms( 
    [
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'search'   => '-en',
    ] 
);
```

that performs a wildcard (`*`) search for `*-en*` within the term's *name* or term's *slug*. Also note the support for  `name__like` and `description__like` input arguments.

If there are large number of tags, then obviously we don't want to fetch thousands of tags, at once. We could limit that number with the  `number` input argument and also use the `offset` for paging. Hopefully the page number argument will be supported soon. The `count` argument only returns the tag  count.

Comment: should i then just loop through terms? like so: foreach($terms as $term) {echo $term->name;}... seems not work like this.. I have only like 30 tags so this method is fine.

Comment: yes, the output of `get_terms()` should be an array of `WP_Term` objects here. Note that it can also return `WP_Error` for e.g a non-existing taxonomy or a number for the count option.

Comment: well this seems not working its not outputting any tags

Comment: I just tested it succesfully.Try first the backend tag search, e.g. `/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag&s=-en` in your backend, it should be a similar `get_terms()` construct.